# E(fx)clipse completely rendered with Javafx

Tags: efxclipse

I would like to know if, in some way, it is possible to start an e(fx)clipse instance, whose view parts are completely rendered with Javafx (editors, palette...).
If I develop a plugin with view contribution in Javafx, can I start "all" eclipse rendered in javafx?
Or e(fx)clipse only allows to insert Javafx components into swt canvas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reply myself: no, it is not possible.
Read last comment on
https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/10/17/efxclipse-0-0-7-released/